# Service Principal to create Resources on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

I have a policy in place for my Subscription that does not allow for the creation of Resource Groups.

However, i have also put in place a Customer Role on the Subscription Level as an owner for the Service Principal which allows it to create RGs.

However, whenever i deploy my IAC via Azure DevOps, it fails still.

I am not sure where i am going wrong. I had a read at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/544294/azure-custom-policy-to-limit-creation-of-a-resourc.html), and the referenced links within but did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot exclude specific users with Azure Policy. Each and every ARM deployment will go through the Policy Engine and will be rejected if it doesn't meet the rule, regardless of who ran the action.

See [Azure Policy and Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview#azure-policy-and-azure-rbac) : *"Azure Policy ensures that resource state is compliant to your business rules without concern for who made the change or who has permission to make a change."*

The link you provided mentions the use of [Azure Blueprints and Deny Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments) - which are objects above unitary Policy and RBAC assignment. Basically a Blueprint is a combination of role assignments, policies, ARM templates and RGs - see [Azure Blueprints overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/overview).

To achieve what you want to do, you could exempt the Policy temporarily, use Blueprints or even make use of [Custom Roles](https://exempt%20the%20Policy%20temporarily), amongst other ways, all depending on your use case.

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is that nobody but the Service Principal can create a Resource Group on my Subscription. This is not possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible, as explained in the last section of my answer. You have determine which scenario suits the best to you, you should ask yourself : can you cope with a temporary policy exemption or is it too risky ? Are custom roles a solution you could think of, considering that no one will be able to have built-in Contributor role at RG level ? Would Blueprint be a fit or is it too limiting/cumbersome ? 
As said, it all depends on your use case - and not only what you want to achieve - it also includes your criteria, your environment/context, etc.